# Images from mysql does not display using php

Tags: php, mysql

Image is successfully fetching from database but it not be shown by the PHP. In place of image it shows a iamge thumbnail.
If I use header('Content-type:image/jpg'); it will show the only thumbnail all page contents disappear.

```
 include 'functions/connect.php';

 $user = $_SESSION['email'];
 $sql = "SELECT photo FROM user WHERE email='$user'";
 $run_sql = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_sql);
 $user_photo =$row['photo'];
 echo"<p><img src='$user_photo'></p>";`
```

Comment: So, your query is supposed to return a URI to the photo? Have you looked at the uri that gets returned? And when you say it returns a thumbnail: is it like a placeholder? A small version of your image? If the latter, that sounds like some resizing happening in the browser.

Comment: What does the page source look like?

Comment: how can I return URL of the photo? what is the code for it?

Comment: You will need to write a script that fetches the image data and then outputs it directly. Then put the URL of the script into the `src` attribute.

Comment: You could change this script so it converts the image to base64, and puts that data into a `data:` URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<img alt="<?php echo $user_photo; ?>" src="uploads/<?php echo $user_photo; ?>" /> // Upload is folder where image was uploaded
```

Comment: image uploaded to the database and directly access from it.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what the field "photo" contains. If the photo field contains the location of the picture on your system, then the way you have done it should work. However, if the field contains the actual photo in binary format (having field data type as 'blob') then you'll need to do the following:

```
file_put_contents("image.jpg", $user_photo);

echo "<p><img src='image.jpg' ></p>";
```